# Find an example of a lattice such that LLL algorithm can't find the shortest vector of the lattice, satisfying

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

I want to find an example of a basis of a lattice of dimension $n$ such that **LLL** algorithm can't find the shortest vector of the lattice, and such that the shortest  vector of this lattice, say $b=c_1b_1+\cdots+c_nb_n$, has small $c_i$, i.e., $c_i \in \{-r,\ldots,r\}$ with small $r$.

Note that $b_i \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $c_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Such example must satisfy $\log_2(2(r+1)) \cdot n \leq 15$, say $n=5$ and $r=4$.

The idea here is to have a treatable value for $2^{\log_2(2(r+1)) \cdot n}$.

I can't find any lattice satisfying this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that LLL guarantees a vector within $2^{(n-1)/2}$ from optimal,  and it tends to behave better than that in practice, $15$ is probably too short of a target. Increasing this limit to $25$ makes it easier to find examples.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I agree, $2^{25}$ is "treatable", but instead of 5 minutes of testing all possibilities, with 25 we have to wait 3.5 days... I will try to increase $n$ or $r$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bruteforce appears to work well enough. The following [Sage script finds an instance quickly](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFj01rwzAMhu8G_wftVAeG6Q4bZJDrTg4M0tsYIV3tRNQfqeK2f382ccZuFcaS_bzyKxsKDpZh1NLicZFmttauO6CbA0X4-OyVUpyZh8pR-_7q0QRynHHmoYFXzi4pvbzli_uEVsOBrvqdM0jRJvSvSfhnSOtSrVQl2srkLU7axqHZy7quC-sSWwcTqpLLlOz1Evub_omBxGDHQBgn1-xmCjd92pU2NODQiy-gcJc-W1aQnPMR0IP6ruCpga6gMmWOI-nhnP8wE_oI7VaorXjw7Cbr_oqi4-wXTj1zVw==&lang=sage):

```
from sage.libs.fplll.fplll import FP_LLL
from sage.libs.fplll.fplll import gen_uniform

n = 5 # dimension
q = 16 # size of matrix entries

while True:
    M = gen_uniform(n, n, q)
    L = M.LLL(delta=0.999)
    S = FP_LLL(L).shortest_vector(algorithm='proved')
    if min([ row.norm() for row in L]) != S.norm():
        break

print M
print L
print min([ row.norm() for row in L])
print S
print S.norm()
```

As a concrete example, the lattice (column vectors)
$$L = 
\begin{pmatrix}
16252&  5541& 48769&  2593& 22395\\
 2404& 46418&  5335& 59631& 29390\\
41816& 27475& 56363& 50417& 62371\\
27419& 53783&  1412& 42344& 55983\\
62503& 52719& 22160&  3940& 64256\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
can be reduced with LLL ($\delta = 0.999$) to
$$B=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1855&  31849 & -6182&  -5480&  16007\\
 23160& -24484 &  2259& -11807&  10586\\
 29450&   -465 &  8167&   2997& -19059\\
 10069&  -8429 & 24671& -21117& -18320\\
  4328& -17879 & 30280&  29190&  24708\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Yet, none of those vectors is the shortest. The shortest vector is $$(-19381, -7964, 16504, -24114, 739),$$ which can be written as $2L_0 - L_1 - L_2 + 2L_3 - L_4$, where $L_i$ is the $i$th row of $L$. So we have $n = 5$ and $r = 2$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, seems nice, I wanted $\delta=3/4$ but $\delta=0.999$ will surely do. Obrigado (?)

Comment: I think, if L[0].norm() != S.norm(): , is enough, instead of, if min([ row.norm() for row in L]) != S.norm():

Comment: `L[0]` is likely, but not guaranteed, to be the shortest vector in the basis.